# How do you say, "the note says"

Tags: узус

In English we say *the sign says*, *the letter says*, etc.  In Russian do you use *говорить* or *говориться*?
Example:

> The sign says no smoking.

Would it be:

> знак говорит не курить

Or how would you interpret this phrase:

> On the door was a note saying they were gone.

Answer (score 9):

This somewhat depends on the context.

"the sign says" - знак гласит, на знаке написано

"the letter says" - в письме написано

"On the door was a note saying they were gone." - На двери была записка о том, что они ушли. В записке на двери было сказано что они ушли.

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation will sound unnatural in most cases, the most closest colloquial form is that one which is used with the verb "написано":

- На двери было написано, что все ушли.
- Написано же, не шуметь!

But with imperative verbs "сказать" is also appropriate and understandable:

- Сказано не курить.

More formal, phrase `On the door was a note saying they were gone` can be translated as `на двери висело объявление/записка о том, что все ушли`.

As for `говорится`, it can be used to translate a slightly different English construction, "it is said that":

- В книге говорится, что не не стоит злоупотреблять алкоголем.

Answer (score 1):

Usually such phrases can be translated using a past tense without an explicit object:

> на знаке написано; or
>   в записке говорилось;
>   etc.

Hence phrase *On the door was a note saying they were gone* could be translated as

> В записке на двери говорилось, что они ушли.

(Note that depending on the context, *they were gone* could be translated into something other than *они ушли*.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use similar wording

> - Инструкция говорит о том, что нужно закрывать дверь.
> - В инструкции не сказано, как быть в такой ситуации.
> - В инструкции говорится о мерах предосторожности.
> - В инструкции написано о другом.